# jQuery Appear Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery appear plugin. I'm having trouble making it work. I tried to attach it to the (window).scroll event but it makes the page slow. If I don't use the scroll, it only fires once. I need it to work again whenever the element becomes visible. Can you give me some tips on how to make it work.

Here's my code:

```
jQuery('.home-section-1').appear(function(){
    jQuery('.page-scroll-indicator .fa.fa-circle').removeClass('active-ind');
    jQuery('.page-scroll-indicator .section-1').addClass('active-ind');
});
```

Comment: `jQuery('.home-section-1').on('appear', function() { ... });` - basically, use `.on` - see docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

As ɴ-ᴀ-ᴛ-ʜ said in his comment, you need to be using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to listen for the appear event.

```
jQuery('.home-section-1').on('appear', function(){
    jQuery('.page-scroll-indicator .fa.fa-circle').removeClass('active-ind');
    jQuery('.page-scroll-indicator .section-1').addClass('active-ind');
});
```

Here's a code snippit showing it working, you'll notice that your method (Method 1) doesn't fire, while the method above (Method 2) does:

```js
/*
* jQuery appear plugin
*
* Copyright (c) 2012 Andrey Sidorov
* licensed under MIT license.
*
* https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear/
*
* Version: 0.3.4
*/
(function($) {
var selectors = [];
var check_binded = false;
var check_lock = false;
var defaults = {
interval: 250,
force_process: false
}
var $window = $(window);
var $prior_appeared;
function process() {
check_lock = false;
for (var index = 0, selectorsLength = selectors.length; index < selectorsLength; index++) {
var $appeared = $(selectors[index]).filter(function() {
return $(this).is(':appeared');
});
$appeared.trigger('appear', [$appeared]);
if ($prior_appeared) {
var $disappeared = $prior_appeared.not($appeared);
$disappeared.trigger('disappear', [$disappeared]);
}
$prior_appeared = $appeared;
}
}
// "appeared" custom filter
$.expr[':']['appeared'] = function(element) {
var $element = $(element);
if (!$element.is(':visible')) {
return false;
}
var window_left = $window.scrollLeft();
var window_top = $window.scrollTop();
var offset = $element.offset();
var left = offset.left;
var top = offset.top;
if (top + $element.height() >= window_top &&
top - ($element.data('appear-top-offset') || 0) <= window_top + $window.height() &&
left + $element.width() >= window_left &&
left - ($element.data('appear-left-offset') || 0) <= window_left + $window.width()) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}
$.fn.extend({
// watching for element's appearance in browser viewport
appear: function(options) {
var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options || {});
var selector = this.selector || this;
if (!check_binded) {
var on_check = function() {
if (check_lock) {
return;
}
check_lock = true;
setTimeout(process, opts.interval);
};
$(window).scroll(on_check).resize(on_check);
check_binded = true;
}
if (opts.force_process) {
setTimeout(process, opts.interval);
}
selectors.push(selector);
return $(selector);
}
});
$.extend({
// force elements's appearance check
force_appear: function() {
if (check_binded) {
process();
return true;
};
return false;
}
});
})(jQuery);

// Your method
jQuery('.home-section-1').appear(function(){
    alert('Method 1');
});

// Using .on
jQuery('.home-section-1').on('appear', function(){
    alert('Method 2');
});
```

```css
.home-section-1 {
    margin-top: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-section-1">Hello World</div>
```

Comment: For some weird reason the .on method is not working... My first method is working but it only fires once, when you scroll back to the element, nothing happens... Your method works if I make a local html file... I found no script errors so far...